# Floating car data / Floating mobile data in open source

Tags: data

Someone know if it's possible to find Floating car data (FCD) or Floating mobile data (FMD) in open source?
I found that you can make live map for airplane with the open source website "opensky network". I wonder if it's possible to try to do the same with car in city.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask